# How run 2 script python in same time?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I explain my need : i wish to run ffmpeg with a python script (that's ok) but i need to know of the script is launched with a blink led connected on the GPIO of my RPI, But i dont know why i can launch my script and start le blink (or just a led on)

Can u help me ? show me the light, please ;)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)

# fonction qui fait clignoter la led 
def blink(led):
        GPIO.output(led,True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(led,False)
        time.sleep(1)

# input of the switch will change the state of the LED
while 1:
        if ( GPIO.input(22) == True ):
                print "start broadcast"
                os.system("sudo /home/pi/videopi/webcam.sh")
                blink(4) << not ok like this !
                time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `os` script runs successfully (I would recommend `subprocess` instead), what you're describing is called concurrency --  https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

I would structure your code like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
from threading import Thread 

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)

# fonction qui fait clignoter la led 
def blink(led):
        while True:
            GPIO.output(led,True)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(led,False)
            time.sleep(1)

# input of the switch will change the state of the LED
while True:
    if ( GPIO.input(22) == True ):
        blinking = Thread(target=blink, args=(4,)) # create thread
        blinking.start() # start blinking
        print("start broadcast")
        os.system("sudo /home/pi/videopi/webcam.sh")
        blinking.join() # stops blinking once webcam.sh completed
        print("broadcast complete")
```